# Amadeus Flight Offers Search API customized search

Tags: amadeus

I'm using [Amadeus Flight Offers Search POST API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) to search flights, I have used some of the search parameters mentioned in the API Documentation and some other parameters that I found in questions of stackoverflow. I'm looking for a documentation that contains all the possible search parameters of the API. I've searched a lot but so far couldn't find anything other than [this document](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/amadeus-node/#flightoffers) and the one I mentioned above. Is there another documentation for Amadeus? Something more specific.
I want to add the "maximum layover time" parameter to my request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look at the [API specification](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) to see what are all the available parameters.

- If you use the `GET` version: all the parameters are explained directly in the interactive part of the API specification.
- If you use the `POST` version: you have to take a look at the model of the body parameter that describes all the parameters (and the structure) you can use:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Anthony for answering. Have you updated the documents since yesterday? It looks different and there was not a Model section there before. Anyways, thanks, it's really helpful.

Comment: Yesterday we have upgraded OAS version 2 to version 3, the display is different but the models have always been there (but it is easier to read and to find with this version).

Comment: And as I checked, you don't have an option for `maximum layover time`.

Comment: You are right, as of today we do not offer a parameter to control the time of the layover you will have to check the response and do it on your side. I added this feedback to our product backlog for future improvments.